How to represent a model fitted using spline transformer + linear regression in an mathematical equation. The data is high dimensional
I have a dataset consisting of 5 features and 1 target. I am using a spline transformer to transform the features and then fit it using linear regression. I am fitting the data with 1st degree and 5 knots of spline transformed features. Now I want to represent the model fit in a mathematical equation that will include the individual terms as well as the interaction terms.
How can I do that?

Since splines are defined piecewise, a single mathematical equation must somehow select the piece you are looking at.
You can e.g. use something like (SIGN(x-3)+1)*(SIGN(x-4)-1)/-4 which is zero for all values of x outside [3,4] and multiply this term by the spline in the range [3,4]. Then you simply sum up all the therms. however, one must be carefull at the knots.

I did not understand what you meant.
I am using a spline transformer to transformer the features and then fit a linear regression.
Just an example, My input shape is (19,5) and when I use a spline transformer, the features are transformed to (19,20) with 1st degree and 5 knots.
Now I use these features to fit a linear regression model. Then I want to represent the fit in terms of an equation.

maybe it would be worth to provide a compelte numerical example for clarification, since with a single point (19,5) you cannot have linear regression.

It is not a single data point, I have 19 data samples, and 5 indicate the number of features.
When I applied a spline transformer to my features the, shape became (19,20) and then I used these features to fit a linear regression model.

please provide the complete dataset (input & results)
